# Differentiating between volume, snapshot and understanding Stop

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I am not very clear in the difference between a `Volume` and a `Snapshot`. When a new instance is created, it automatically creates a `snapshotID` like `snap-ad8e61t8` in `Volume` under `Elastic Block Store` but keeps nothing in the snapshot section under `Elastic Block Store`.

- **What is a volume?**

While creating a new instance, it describes (along with snapshotID):

```
A snapshot is a backup of an EC2 volume that's stored in S3. You can create
a new volume using data stored in a snapshot by entering the snapshot's ID. You can search 
for public snapshots by typing text in the Snapshot field.
Descriptions are case-sensitive.
```

But it stores under `Elastic Block Store` or `EBS`.

- **Why is that and what does it mean?** (There is a difference between S3 and EBS)

I kept some files on AWS EC2 instance's desktop and then clicked `stop`. After I restarted it, I expected my data to have been lost but it was there on the desktop.

- **Does it always backup my data when instance is stopped?**

Answer (score 1):

A volume is a virtual harddisk. A snapshot is an image (backup) of a volume, which is stored in S3, remote and cheap. You can create empty volumes, and volumes from snapshots.

If you have a volume data1 which is 10GB big, and you need it to be 20GB, or you need to change it from magnetic to ssd, then you create a snapshot of that volume, and create a new volume from that snapshot.

Of course you can also create a new empty volume without using a snapshot, and then rsync all files to the new volume. An empty volume doesn't have a snapshot-id.

The snapshot-id you see in the volume details is the id of the snapshot used to create the volume.

S3 is the remote and cheap storage for Amazon, and independent of your instances. You can kill and terminate your instance and its volumes without affecting the data in S3.

EBS is the local storage for your instance. It is persistent, which means that if you shut down the server, the disk is still there. The alternative for local storage is ephemeral, which is not persistent. If you shutdown the server, the disk is gone. It will survive a restart though. If the server crashes (hardware can fail), the disk is gone. This may sound bad, but if the server is based on an AMI it can be recreated quickly. The AMI should be configured to your needs of course.